# How to manage Realm Notification Tokens centrally

Tags: swift, enums, notifications, realm, token

I have a number of notification tokens scattered around my app's classes. I would like to create a class, e.g. a RealmNotificationTokensManager, to keep track of instantiated tokens to be able to know what tokens are active at a specific point of time or view in the app to make sure to invalidate them timely etc.

In total, there are around 35 notification tokens in my app.

Besides having all these tokens as properties of the manager class, I'd like to be able to group them in an array to be able to run queries on it. But if I maintain that array manually, e.g. if I add a new token, I need to make sure I also add it to the array of all tokens. This is a bit error prone since one can forget to add the new token to the array.

As far as I understand there might be away to make it safer by using an `enum` and maybe `CaseIterable` protocol but I cannot find a way to do it.

Would anybody give some direction how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it should be fairly straight forward to create a 'centralized' notification manager. Keep mind this is very bare bones for brevity but it's how we do it.

Suppose we have a PersonClass and DogClass and we want to add observers to those types of objects. We will have a class var that contains the people and dog results as well as a var representing the manager

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var peopleResults: Results<PersonClass>? = nil
    var dogResults: Results<DogClass>? = nil
    let manager = NotificationManager()
```

and then somewhere along the way we'll load in the people and dogs into results and add an observer

```
func observePeople() {
    var token = NotificationToken()
    token = self.peopleResults!.observe { changes in
            switch changes {
               ...
            }
        }

    self.manager.notificationArray.append(token)
}
```

and then dogs

```
func observeDogs() {
    var token = NotificationToken()
    token = self.dogResults!.observe { changes in
            switch changes {
               ...
            }
        }

    self.manager.notificationArray.append(token)
}
```

and the notification manager would look like this

```
class NotificationManager {
    var notificationArray = [NotificationToken]()
}
```

now this next part is use case dependent

> if I add a new token, I need to make sure I also add it to the array
> of all tokens. This is a bit error prone since one can forget to add
> the new token to the array.

I get the gist of that statement so if you know the exact notifications you will be using, those could be implemented into the manager itself. So install of creating tokens everywhere in the app, do it all within the manager

For example

```
class NotificationManager {
    var notificationArray = [NotificationToken]()
    
    func observeDogs() {
        let dogResults = realm.objects(DogClass.self)
        var token = NotificationToken()
        token = dogResults.observe { changes in
            switch changes {
                //..
            }
        }
            
        self.notificationArray.append(token)
    }
}
```

then when you want to observe Dogs, one-line will do it

```
func observeDogs() {
    self.manager.observeDogs()
}
```

If you want to 'lock it down' then using enums is a great idea

```
enum Observers {
    case people
    case dogs
}

class NotificationManager {
    var notificationArray = [NotificationToken]()
    
    func addObserverTo(whatToObserve: Observers) {
        switch whatToObserve {
        case .people:
            //add people observer
        case .dogs:
            //add dogs observer
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

and then called like this

```
self.manager.addObserverTo(whatToObserve: .people)
```